# How do I fix this "cannot resolve constructor" error?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a dialogue box with a positive bottom that changes the activity from `SignupAcitvity` to `MainActivity`. So I used the intent method to do this. However, once I tried this, I got the following error message:`Cannot Resolve constructor 'Intent(com.androidcodefinder.loginscreendemo.Profile.ExampleDialogue, java.lang.Class<com.androidcodefinder.loginscreendemo.MainActivity>)'`. Can you help me fix this?

My code:

```
public class ExampleDialogue extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialayout,null);
        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Confirm Your Email")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.class, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you are getting this error is because you are **in the `ExampleDialogue` activity**, but you are **starting an intent from `SignUpActivity.class`** to `MainActivity.class`. If you want to go to `MainActivity.class`, you will have to do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also, it can't resolve the constructor so just add this default constructor, which you can change as you wish:

```
public ExampleDialogue(){
    //Constructor code.
}
```

Comment: That was a really good thing to point out. I tried your code however, and the error is still there.

Comment: I just made a change that I think will fix the problem.

Comment: Please mark it as accepted if it helped you so that others can refer to it. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.class, MainActivity.class)
```

However, Intent has no constructor with 2 classes as arguments. Hence the error.

What you want, is to use the constructor `Intent(Context, Class<?>)`. Specifially, in your case you do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
```